# Customize Youtube subscribe as photoshop design?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

In my app, I have to create a subscribe button for my company channel. So far I used this code :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCvO93j-c1ZJpQOQlRhy-buw" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

However the problem is the result is not like the design:

[Youtube subscribe button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCubc.png)

How can I make it look like that one?

Comment: Have you included CSS with `g-ytsubscribe` class definition into your page?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's not working.